# SVN checkout not working

Tags: tortoisesvn

When I try to checkout with TortoiseSVN, the checkout dialog window hangs and no buttons respond.

I am under Windows 7 and use a VPN. On Windows XP it works.
I deactivated the firewall.

Comment: My suggestion is to install Wireshark on both Windows 7 and XP and find a difference in communication.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but when my VPN disconnects everything related to it hangs... shell, everything. Maybe you are losing your connection somehow?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but it isn't VPN. I checked my VPN connection, everything is ok with it